# Allowing Fixed div to expand in height with content

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, fixed

I am having an issue with a small project I'm working on. I'll post my code below, but first a run down of what I'm trying to accomplish and my problem(s) thus far.

I have an absolutely positioned div (#home) positioned top/left:0 of the page, and has a width and height of 100% of browser. I then have a fixed div (#content) that is positioned the same as #home, top/left:0. The z-index on #home is higher than that on #content, allowing #home to rest on top of #content, and reveal #content when the page is scrolled. I had to set a height for my body,html elements to allow the page to scroll. My problem is with the fixed div - how can I allow this div to expand (overflow) in height with the content, and not be cut off at the bottom of the page? Min-height did not work.

### CSS

```
 body, html {
    background:white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Regular';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200%;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 3000;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="content">
        first<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>sdfd<br/><br/><br/><br/>last<br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
```

***[See Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/)***

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Bonus points for help allowing #home to expand in height as needed as well, without interrupting or covering part of #content on page scroll. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: can u show us an image. what do you expect to do?

Comment: looks like you want the #home to cover the whole #content at all time? that's some kind of strange requirement.

Comment: he wants to make home covers content for the first sight, and when you scroll down you can see all the content of content div, now you can only see the early words only because the height is not adjusted to fit all the content at once. he wants to fix it

Comment: @kingking Not quite - I want #home to cover content on the top 100% of the page only. When the page scrolls, #home scrolls up revealing the fixed div #content. My issue is allowin #content to expand in height as the content of said div requires. As of now, #content cuts content off at the bottom. Hope this is clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Ahmedskaya Exactly! I suppose I could also ask if there is an easier, established method of achieving the result I'm looking for. I want #home to be 100% width and height of the browser (not the entire page, but the viewport/browser). When the page is scrolled, I want #home to scroll up revealing the div #content underneath. Content will be roughly 300% of the browser-height, but I need #content to be able to adjust it's height for the content as when the page is resized, extra height on #content may be necessary.

I assumed creating an absolute div (#home) positioned over #content would work

Comment: try this https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js

Comment: Oh, I see! so like a curtain raise that reveals the content underneath?

Comment: @MrRioku correct - my issue was allowing the fixed div (which is beneath the blue div as shown in my example) to display all the content vertically. To get this to work, I had to use javascript to change the position from fixed to absolute. Any idea if there is a way to achieve this result with only CSS? This method seems to be working pretty perfectly, but I'd rather a pure CSS method.

Comment: Indeed a very hard thing to do, but im thinking

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/1/

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2000;

}
```

Comment: No- but thank you. I wanted the lower div (#content) to be fixed, so when the page scrolls that div is sort-of revealed beneath the top div (#home). That is why I need #content to fixed - but I'm hoping that there is a way to allow this div to auto-expand in height as the content requires.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using simple jQuery. I wish I had found a CSS alternative, but I found that explaining my problem & expected outcome was just as hard as solving the problem itself. Hopefully this working example with better demonstrate what I've been referring to, and you all can inform me of a more efficient alternative if there is one.

**[My Solution & Example of Expected Outcome](http://jsfiddle.net/LHn8E/1/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        var winheight = $("#home").height();

        var curr = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(curr >= winheight){

            $("div.pagesContainer").attr("id", "pagesAlt");

        }
        else
        {

            $("div.pagesContainer").attr("id", "pages");

        }


    });
```